# dropbox api usage in nodejs "Bad oauth_signature for oauth_signature_method"

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api

I have been trying to connect to dropbox server and use the api, but I'm failing at the first step itself. When i'm requesting for the request token, I'm getting Bad oauth_signature error in nodejs.

The code that i'm using to connect to api is as follows.(I'm using https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox/blob/master/README.md library/sdk for nodejs)

```
/*
 * dropbox handlers controller.
 */

var dbox = require('dbox')
   ,querystring = require("querystring")

var client = dbox.createClient({
    app_key    : 'my-key',             // required
    app_secret : 'my-secret',           // required
    root       : 'sandbox'            // optional (defaults to sandbox)
  })

exports.index = function(req, res){

  client.request_token(function(status, reply){
    console.log(status)
    console.log(reply)
  // {
  //   oauth_token        : "h89r0sdfdsfwiko",  // required
  //   oauth_token_secret : "8hielfflk7100mv",  // required
  // }
  })
```

the result i'm getting in my console is as follows

c:\tmp\dropbox>node app.js
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
oauth_consumer_key=[my key]&oauth_signature=faawn09ehmfe25i%2526&oauth_ti
mestamp=1324643574&oauth_nonce=132464357437334176&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTE
XT&oauth_version=1.0
403
{ '{"error": "Bad oauth_signature for oauth_signature_method \'PLAINTEXT\'"}': u
ndefined }

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: see if this helps u http://community.freshbooks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=6618

Comment: I appreciate ur help. But I posted this after trying different ways and browsed a lot. The link u posted is not helping me :(

Comment: Thanks every one. Problem solved. If anyone have the similar problem, use the same library that I mentioned in the first post, but in ../dbox/lib/oauth.js file find the following line options["oauth_signature_method"] = "PLAINTEXT", and change it to options["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1",

Comment: one more modification i forgot to mention before is that all the urls with version 1 are not working. instead urls like https://api.dropbox.com/0/oauth/access_token are working. note that 0 in the url instead of 1. If any dropbox developer is watching this, can you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: the /0/ urls will only work with old app keys, created before v1 was v1.  Moving forward, all API calls must be to /1/ end points.   Regarding the signature issue, see if you can get ouath_signature_method="PLAINTEXT" to work.  With plaintext "signing" you don't need to include nonces or timestamps, and creating the "signature" is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks @brbob. Information given by you helped me to solve my problem. There was a small bug in the library that I'm using. Now everything is working fine. Thanks everyone whoever gave their suggestions

Answer (score 4):

This is the author of node-dbox. This issue has been resolved as of version 0.2.2.

Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I took the approach of using the [passport](http://passportjs.org/) module along with its companion [passport-dropbox](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-dropbox) module to handle the routes required for the authentication handshake with Dropbox. Once you receive the token and token secret passed in the Dropbox callback, store them in session state or wherever. Then you can then pass them to node-dbox in subsequent Dropbox API calls. The author of passport has a nice example on GitHub here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-dropbox/tree/master/examples/login

```
passport.use(new DropboxStrategy({
  consumerKey: DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
  consumerSecret: DROPBOX_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: APP_URL + '/auth/dropbox/callback'
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  var user = {
    provider: 'dropbox',
    displayName: profile.displayName,
    email: profile.emails[0].value,
    // I'm choosing to store the token and tokenSecret on the user.
    // The keys must be as shown below to be compatible with node-dbox
    dboxToken: {'oauth_token': token, 'oauth_token_secret': tokenSecret}
  };

  return done(null, user);
}));


app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
  var dboxClient = dboxApp.client(req.user.dboxToken);

  dboxClient.metadata('/', {}, function(status, reply) {
    res.render('files', {
      pathMetaData: reply,
      user: req.user
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix that issue you just need to apply what is mentioned here :

https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox/issues/3

On line 28 of Oauth.js signature is being encoded twice.

```
var getSignature = function(tokenSecret){
   return encode(consumerSecret) + "&" + encode(tokenSecret)
}
var signature = encode(getSignature(secret))
```

Changing it to the following solves the problem of not being able to receive an oauth token.

```
var signature = getSignature(secret)
```

Thx